# Are houses / buildings built on top of existing tents?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Two part question:

I've recently picked out a spot for Blathers' tent. However, due to the nature of my island (not sure how common this is), I only have access to 1/3 of it, with the majority of the island being blocked off by a pair of rivers.

Suffice it to say, compromises had to be made, and Blathers is moving into a tent on the beach, rather than the (currently) inaccessible location I'd intended.

1. Does the museum get built on top of Blathers' tent? Or do you get
   to pick a site for it, same as when placing tents?
2. Is there any way to move houses / buildings after the fact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, houses are built atop the tents' footprints, both yours and the museum's.

After you build Nook's Resident Services [you can relocate your house](https://www.msn.com/en-us/entertainment/gaming/how-to-move-your-house-in-animal-crossing-new-horizons/ar-BB11spWZ) and [the completed museum](https://heavy.com/games/2020/03/can-you-move-blathers-tent-in-animal-crossing-new-horizons/) for a cost (50k bells).